# How do I effectively add sound to a button in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html

I need to know this for a school project, I need the button to play a sound onclick. I tried using `<button>` and an `<audio>` tag, but they don't seem to work. CSS would be an alternative. The only thing that's worked is:

```
<form action="https://bestringtoness.com/sounds/mp3/darth-vader-noooo.mp3">
  <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
</form>
```

(actual code I'm using)

But it's very inefficient, and I need to go back and press 'Run' over and over just to click different options.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `audio` tag like this :

```html
<audio id="a" src="https://bestringtoness.com/sounds/mp3/darth-vader-noooo.mp3" autoplay="false" ></audio>
<input type="submit" onclick="play()" value="Yes" />
    <script>
    function play() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("a");
          sound.play();
      }
    </script>
```